# Can a controller consist of a single zero? -Control systems

Tags: control-system, pid-controller, stability

I'm trying to solve a problem in which the transfer function is this : $$G(s)=\frac{2}{s^2+\frac{s}{3}+1}$$
I'm asked to make a controller to move the poles so that they have damping rato ζ=1. Drawing the root locus I see that I need to add a zero so that the poles meet on the real axis( with a proper gain k). However, can a controller consist of a single zero? Meaning it will be of this form $$C(s)=k(s+p)$$ Because I read somewhere that the controller has to be causal and this is not.

[image]

Comment: Wh ymmis that non causal?

Comment: I don't think you can. The original PID also features a zero, the \$k_d\$ term. As \$s\$ approaches infinity, the gain also becomes infinite and stability is at stake. This is the reason why you need to force gain roll-off at high frequencies with an added pole. The PID becomes the filtered-PID in which the \$k_d\$ is associated with a pole. Same for your case I believe, you need to force the compensator gain roll off at high frequencies. See slide 15 in this document http://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202012.pdf.